# Extending Web App

Tags: branding

I need to set up an Intranet portal for Employees and an Extranet Portal for vendors.

I am looking to extend a web app to create Extranet Portal and allow Forms Based Authentication on it. Is it possible to have a different look and feel and navigation of each?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

this is easily done.

Look up master page branding, you can deploy a separate template on every site collection you create. You can create custom authentication, navigation, profiles, metadata, sites, you think it a different site collection is just different and can house a totally different solution.

In theory you can have 100's of site collections all with a different look and feel.

A good starting point if you want to build it from scratch.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-sharepoint-master-pages-HA102019628.aspx

Otherwise there are plenty of starting point master pages and templates for each content type, and plenty of advanced and simple customisations you can achieve.

You're basic topology would be:

Site collection 1 - Intranet
Site collection 2 - Extranet

You can have multiple site collections for each, I would build these maybe pointing at different subdomains but on the same server and you could even have a site collection per department if the business is large enough.

If you have any more specific questions, just ask. Sharepoint branding can be complex but it doesn't have too be. 1 google will bring back hundreds of tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your response Hugh. The issue is that we need to have them both in one site-collection. Both sites will have access to the same data however the Admins can manage security on the items/list appropriately therefore limiting vendors access to the records.  The URLs of the Portal will be as follows:       www.xyz.com/intranet          and www.xyz.com/extranet                 The look and feel of both portals has to be customized along with the Navigation menu.   Thanks

Comment: In that case, with the new information marius's answer would be the easiest too implement.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, pointing to the same content. Even though this translates to 2 different IIS sites, in terms of SharePoint, they both target same Content Database, as well as settings for the same Site Collection.

In your case, you could rather use Explicit Paths (Intranet vs Extranet), with 2 site collections and then setup individual settings, but at  the same time these would be different content.

I would however recomand create another, call it "site section" (even sub-sites would do) where you would share common data, instead of fiddling with security permissions which could go out of hand really quick. Use Content Publishing, or the excellent Send-To feature or Content Organizer to move content around.

Comment: Thanks Marius. I will create two seperate sites within the same site collection.

Comment: Did it helped you solve your problem? Please make sure to mark appropriate answer or ask for updates from Author to share with others. Thank you.